# vue app object is not type of object

Tags: laravel-5, gulp, vuejs2, vue-component

I've started to build vue.js app with Laravel using single-file components. The problem is with my app object: it is a DOM, not a Vue object and app won't work properly.

When I start my app, components are rendered properly, `vue-devtools` recognizes Vue 2.2.6, evertything seems to work in the right way.

But when I type

```
console.log(app)
```

in chrome console I see a DOM object:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

What more, when I try to change title property (and wanted to see changed `hello` component on screen) just by typing

```
app.title = "awesomness"
```

in console, my component wouldn't change, but only my `div#app`: (typed `console.log(app)`

```
<div id="app" title="awesomness"></div>
```

The question is: **why**? Samples below.

Test component `Hello.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>{{ greeting }} World!</p>
    </div>

<script>
    module.exports = {
        props: ['greeting'],
        data: function() {
            return {
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    p {
        color: red;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

part of my index/index view from laravel:

```
<div id="app">
    <hello :greeting="title"></hello>
</div>
```

and finally my `/resources/assets/js/app.js` file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Hello from './components/Hello.vue'

Vue.component('hello', Hello);

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        title: 'Hello Vue!',
        todos: [
            { text: 'task 1' },
            { text: 'task 2' },
            { text: 'task 3' },
            { text: 'task 4' }
        ],
    }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most browsers, the `id` attribute of an HTML element is [exposed in the global scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables) as a variable. So, when you type `console.log(app)`, it is returning the element that has the id, "app".

You've named your Vue with the same variable name, `app`. But you also used `var` which makes it restricted to the containing scope (meaning, not a global variable). When you build an application using most build tools these days (webpack for example), the code you write is contained in a wrapping scope (a function). So the `app` variable that is the result of `new Vue()` is not accessible to you globally. If you wanted to make it accessible globally, you would probably write

```
window.app = new Vue()
```

However, you probably want to just rename it as well.

```
window.myApp = new Vue()
```

if you are going to call the template for app the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Although, the answer to you question is to give your `app` variable a global scope with

```
window.app = new Vue({...});
```

Do you have Vue devtools extension in your Chrome browser? If not, please install it. With that installed, its now history to name my Vue instance something like `window.app` for the sake of debugging. Here is a link, you will find it really useful.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en